Python extracting a high resolution icon from an EXE file
I'm trying to extract .ico files from executable files
i found this code on the website
import win32ui
import win32gui
import win32con
import win32api

ico_x = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CXICON)
ico_y = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CYICON)

large, small = win32gui.ExtractIconEx(r"C:\z\NEW ICON\a.exe",0)
win32gui.DestroyIcon(small[0])

hdc = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle( win32gui.GetDC(0) )
hbmp = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
hbmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap( hdc, ico_x, ico_x )
hdc = hdc.CreateCompatibleDC()

hdc.SelectObject( hbmp )
hdc.DrawIcon( (0,0), large[0] )

hbmp.SaveBitmapFile( hdc, 'icon.bmp') 
 

this does work but it always gives me a 32x32 icon
and i know the exe file contains higher resolution icons since i opened it with 7zip

Icons extracted from exe files are intellectual property.

okay thank you for the kind words

To extract the largest icon you should iterate through ALL icons and find the largest:
import os
import win32ui
import win32gui
import win32con
import win32api
import ctypes

lib = ctypes.windll.user32

def save_icon(icon_handle, size, save_path):
    hdc = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(win32gui.GetDC(0))
    hbmp = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
    hbmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, size, size)
    hdc = hdc.CreateCompatibleDC()
    hdc.SelectObject(hbmp)
    hdc.DrawIcon((0, 0), icon_handle)
    hbmp.SaveBitmapFile(hdc, save_path)

def extract_largest_icon(exe_path, output_file):
    large_icons,small_icons = win32gui.ExtractIconEx(exe_path, 0, 50)
    
    all_icons =large_icons+ small_icons

    if not all_icons:
        print("No iconsss found in executable")
        return

    largest_icon = None
    largest_size= 0
    for icon in all_icons:
        icon_info = win32gui.GetIconInfo(icon)
        icon_width =lib.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CXICON)
        icon_height = lib.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CYICON)
        
        icon_size = icon_width * icon_height
        if icon_size > largest_size:
            largest_size = icon_size
            largest_icon = icon

    if largest_icon:
        print(f"Saving largest icon..")
        save_icon(largest_icon, win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CXICON),output_file)
        win32gui.DestroyIcon(largest_icon)

exe_file = r"C:\z\NEW ICON\a.exe"
output_file = r"C:\path\to\output\icon_largest.bmp"

extract_largest_icon(exe_file, output_file)


dude you're a genius thank you
